# How to iterate over the following array of objects inside another object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops

These are the objects and a simple function:

```
const getTotalYield = plants => {
    console.log(plants);
}

const corn = {
    name: "corn",
    yield: 3,
};
const pumpkin = {
    name: "pumpkin",
    yield: 4,
};
const crops = [
    { crop: corn, numCrops: 5 },
    { crop: pumpkin, numCrops: 2 },
];
```

I have to call it like this:

```
getTotalYield({crops})

output so far:
{
  crops: [ { crop: [Object], numCrops: 5 }, { crop: [Object], numCrops: 2 } ]
}
```

So how do I access the first object and then work with the properties in the array?

Answer (score 1):

You can access your fields inside the object like this.
This snipet multiples the num of crops by the yields of each crop and them add it to the total yields.

```js
const getTotalYield = plants => {
  let totalY =0;
  plants.forEach(function(element){
    totalY += (element.crop.yield)*element.numCrops;
  });
  console.log(totalY);
}

const corn = {
    name: "corn",
    yield: 3,
};
const pumpkin = {
    name: "pumpkin",
    yield: 4,
};
const crops = [
    { crop: corn, numCrops: 5 },
    { crop: pumpkin, numCrops: 2 },
];

getTotalYield(crops);
```

Comment: Oke thank you! I have to work with calling the function like this, with the curly braces:
getTotalYield({crops})
Then I get a typeError: plants.forEach is not a function.
How would I go about calling the function like that?

Comment: what framework or library are you working with to solve the {crops} with  curly braces into data?

Comment: I am using the testing library Jest

Comment: " typeError: plants.forEach is not a function " means whatever data " {crops} " return is not an array, it may have a wraper of some sort, i don't know anything about jest. Try to console.log({crops}) to see what kind of object it is.